# Is a type-2 system always unstable?

Tags: control-system, stability

If there are multiple poles at the origin, a system is unstable.

A type-2 system will be have \$s^2\$ in the denominator. So it should be unstable, right?

Comment: There are many transfer functions that have s^2 in the denominator but that circuit isn't unstable.

Comment: depends upon the gain and the phase, perhaps provided by an explicit "compensator"

Comment: Are you referring to open-loop poles or closed-loop poles?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

I think the previous answers are confusing system type with system order. To clarify, a type II (type 2) system is a system with two open loop integrators and unity gain negative feedback. An integrator is simply a pole at the origin. A fact about stable type II systems is they have no steady state error for a step and linear ramp input. There is a finite constant tracking error for a quadratically increasing input, and infinite error (output can not track) a cubically increasing input.

For stability let's talk in terms of BIBO. BIBO means "bounded input, bounded output". So a unit step input will result in an output that does not increase forever. If we consider an integrator, we can observe that for an unit step (bounded input) we receive a ramp output (unbounded output). Therefore an integrator system is not BIBO stable. Adding more integrators does not change this.

A type II system has a open loop transfer function of the form:

$$\frac{(b_ms^m + b_{m-1}s^{m-1}+\dots +b_1s+b_0)}{s^2(a_ns^n + a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\dots +a_1s+a_0)}$$

This on it's own is unstable (BIBO wise). There are two integrators meaning the output can increase without bound when presented a bounded input. However, when we apply unity gain feedback, the pole locations will change. This may stabilize the system. There are systems where the closed loop transfer function is still not BIBO stable.

---

### Example System 1 (Stable Type II)

Let's look at an open loop transfer function of:

$$\frac{2s+1}{s^2(s+1)}$$

With unity gain feedback we get a closed loop transfer function of:

$$\frac{2s+1}{s^3+s^2+2s+1}$$

which has poles at:

-0.2151 + 1.3071i

-0.2151 - 1.3071i

-0.5698 + 0.0000i

which all have negative real part. Thus, the closed loop system is stable.

---

### Example System 2 (Unstable)

This isn't always the case, let's look at an open loop transfer function of:

$$\frac{1}{s^2(s+1)}$$

With unity gain feedback we get a closed loop transfer function of:

$$\frac{1}{s^3+s^2+1}$$

which has poles at:

-1.4656 + 0.0000i

0.2328 + 0.7926i

0.2328 - 0.7926i

There are a pair of poles with positive real part, thus the system is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

A type II system will always be unstable in open loop implementation. Consider for example this type II system
$$H_{ol}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2} $$
Inverse Laplace-transforming to find the impulse response gives
$$h(t) = \mathcal{L}\bigg\{\frac{1}{s^2} \bigg\}^{-1} = t $$
which shows that \$h(t) \rightarrow \infty \$ for \$t \rightarrow \infty \$. So obviously, the system is inherently unstable.

Answer (score -1):

**In general, a system is stable, if all real parts of the poles are negative.**

It is well described [here](http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf)

---

> Is a type 2 system is always unstable?

No, the order of a system says nothing about its stability.

> If there are multiple poles at origin, that system is unstable.

This is a marginal case. It can be either unstable or slightly stable, depending on how many poles there are at the origin.